# Trouble trying to loop a tree recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I'm trying to loop over a tree and it items in order to look for a node by its `id`, this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hi there</title>
  <script>
    function getNode(node, id) {
      if (node.id === id) {
        return node;
      }
      if (node.items) {
        for (let x of node.items) {
          return getNode(x, id);
        }
      }
    }

    function load() {
      var nodes = [{
        id: 0,
        label: 'root',
        items: [{
          id: 1,
          label: 'one'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          label: 'two'
        }, {
          id: 3,
          label: 'three'
        }, {
          id: 4,
          label: 'four'
        }]
      }];
      var n = nodes[0];
      var node = getNode(n, 3);
      console.log(node);
    }

    window.onload = load();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm facing the problem when I call `load` the recursive function returns undefined. Any hint on how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (let x of node.items) {
  return getNode(x, id);
}
```

This will look at the very first item, and regardless of what it finds, it returns the result of getNode. So it walks down to the item with id=1, then returns undefined, and continues returning undefined back up the stack. It never moves on to the rest of the items (ie, the loop doesn't do anything).

Instead, it should return only if it found it, or move on to the next item.

```js
function getNode(node, id) {
  if (node.id === id) {
    return node;
  }
  if (node.items) {
    for (let x of node.items) {
      var result = getNode(x, id);
      if (result) {
        return result; //<<---- only returning if we found it
      }
    }
  }
}

function load() {
  var nodes = [{
    id: 0,
    label: 'root',
    items: [{
      id: 1,
      label: 'one'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      label: 'two'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      label: 'three'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      label: 'four'
    }]
  }];

  var n = nodes[0];

  var node = getNode(n, 3);
  console.log(node);
}

load();
```

Comment: it was a hit! thanks... in five minutes I'll mark it as the solution!

Answer (score -2):

You cannot do recursive on this because there is no "items" property of items[0], so the recursion stops when it comes to

```
{
    id: 1,
    label: "one"
}
```

and return undefined.

Comment: take a look at the fixed code, copy it and run it, it works.